# Why my input with ng-model doesn't bind data to other element?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have ASP.NET MVC5 application.
I included script like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And I also did:

```
   <input ng-model="someTest" type="text" />
            <h1>Hello {{someTest}}</h1>
```

But when I write something into input, my `<h1>` doesnt update!
Console is clear, no errors, script is loaded correctly.
All I see on website is **EXACTLY**:

```
Hello {{someTest}}
```

What is wrong?

Even when I download script and include directly to project, problem is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need the ng-app tag, unless you have it somewhere that you aren't showing:

```
<div ng-app>
   <input ng-model="someTest" type="text" />
            <h1>Hello {{someTest}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Ohh. Thanks! I missed that on demo "The basics" on http://angularjs.org/
Yes, there is ng-app but to <html> element.
Thank you!